# Find the sum of the series: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{3^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{3^n}$$

Here is all my steps:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{3^n}=2\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$$

But after?

Comment: Do you know there's formula for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n$ when $|r|<1$?

Comment: I supposed that is equal with 0

Comment: No... that's $1 + r+ r^2 + r^3 + \cdots $, so if $r>0$, this term is not zero. You might be fixing up with $\lim_{n\to \infty} r^n.$

Comment: It's a geometric series

Comment: So there's a formula, do you know that.

Comment: It will be $\frac{1}{1-r}$, but after how can I continue?

Comment: Yes, so now there are two geometric series in the expression, just use the formula (for two different $r$'s, of course) and you will find the answer.

Comment: Oh, so the final result will be someting: $2\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{3}{2}\rightarrow \frac{9}{2}$

Comment: Yes, indeed. ${}{}$

Comment: Was so easy.. thanks, don't put as answer?

Comment: No it's not the the same, the formula is $\frac{1}{1-r} - 1 = \frac{r}{1-r}$ (that $1$ comes from the $n=0$ term)

Comment: Yes, I realized after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only the formula for geometric series (for $|r|<1$):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n = \frac{1}{1-r}.$$

Now use $r = \frac 23$ and $r = \frac 13$ and you are done.